# Backbone. Dispatch/listen to events between views

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

Im a bit confused over how to handle events between views in Backbone. Right now i have two partial views rendered at the same time on a website. Now i want one of the views to dispatch an event that the other view can listen to. How would i do that?

In the view that dispatches the event i run:

```
this.trigger("myEvent")
```

And in the view listening i run:

```
this.bind('myEvent', this.myFunc);
```

But nothing seem to happen at all.

Comment: Or is this simply a bad practice?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're triggering an event on `v1` with:

```
this.trigger('myEvent'); // this is v1
```

then you'd have to listen to events from `v1` with:

```
v1.on('myEvent', this.myFunc); // this is, say, v2 here.
```

The events aren't global, they come from specific objects and you have to listen to those specific objects if you want to receive their events.

If you bind the views directly to each other, you'll quickly have a tangled mess where everything is directly tied to everything else. The usual solution is to create your own event bus:

```
// Put this where ever it makes sense for your application, possibly
// a global, possible something your your app's global namespace, ...
var event_bus = _({}).extend(Backbone.Events);
```

Then `v1` would send events through the `event_bus`:

```
event_bus.trigger('myEvent');
```

and `v2` would listen to the `event_bus`:

```
this.listenTo(event_bus, 'myEvent', this.myFunc);
```

I've also switched from [`bind`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) to [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) since `listenTo` makes it easier to prevent zombies.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yb9TY/

Comment: Thanks for the event bus idea. I was looking how to decouple my code.