# calling a view from another view in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have menu item that when clicked should open a chat panel that is part of a different view. Today is my first day looking at Backbone and im a little confused about how I can call a function on another view when the element is clicked.

I want something like the following on the menu view:

```
view.$('.wkVideoCall')
    .on('click', function() {
        wk.ui.videoChat.videoChatView.open();
        wk.ui.videoChat.openForChatUser();
    });
```

Where `wk.ui.videoChat.videoChatView` is the view that has `.open()` as a method.

But the above is not working, is there an event like change but for click that i can be using? or some sort of bind function?

I know have something like this:
**View 1 (menu):**

```
events: {
        'click .wkVideoCall': 'openVideoChat'
    },
    openVideoChat: function() {
        var videoChatView = new wk.ui.videoChat.videoChatView();
        videoChatView.render();

    },
```

**View 2 (chat panel):**

```
(function() {

    var self = wk.ui.videoChat;

    self.VideoChatView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: function() {
            [0];
            return wk.core.template.load('videoChatTmpl')[0];
        },

        initialize: function() {

            var view = this,
                model = view.model,
                $el = view.$el;


            .on('myEvent', this.open);

            view.$('.wkUnmuteVideo')
                .on('click', function() {
                    self.muteMyVideo(false);
                });

            view.$('.wkUnmuteAudio')
                .on('click', function() {
                    self.muteMyAudio(false);
                });

            view.$('.wkOptions')
                .on('focus', function() {
                    self.showOptions();
                })
                .on('blur', function() {
                    self.hideOptions();
                });
        },

        render: function() {
            console.log("inside");
        }

    });

})();
```

But nothing is logged

Comment: Normally you have `click .wkVideoCall` in the view's `events` and then you'd create a new view for the chat that would take care of things.

Comment: @muistooshort looking into what you said I i added the events key but im still not sure how to have the event called on another veiw?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this event bus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20817516/479863) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you click you should render or re-render a subview as muistooshort wrote.

This is a pretty good example : http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/

And there is plenty of tutorials out there.